# closing multiple GLUT windows independently

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

In my GLUT program i have created two windows. when i try to close one window entire program shuts down. can anyone tell how to avoid it.

My code to create window is as follows

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(ww,wh);
    window1 = glutCreateWindow("sample");
    glutReshapeFunc(changeSize);
    glutIdleFunc(renderScene);
    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
    window3 = glutCreateWindow("sample2");
    glutReshapeFunc(changeSize);
    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene2);
    glutIdleFunc(renderScene2);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recall GLUT being able to close windows independently in the same thread, like that. As you only use a single `glutMainLoop()` call to get them going, thereby when the *main loop* is killed for one window, it's killed for all of them.

*You could try creating the windows in their own Thread. That might work, but I'm not entirely sure.*

Something else you could try, is to use [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) instead, using GLFW, you need to create the *main loop* etc, yourself. Bottom line, that's much easier to use and it gives you a lot more control, over your OpenGL programs. Also if you don't already have it, you should get something like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @datenwolf You need to update your GLFW knowledge, version 3.0 supports multiple windows. http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/news.html

Answer (score 0):

You've just left the capabilities of GLUT with this demand. But you're lucky: GLUT =/= OpenGL and there are many other frameworks that will satisfy your needs. How about you take a look at Qt, which offers you not only a runtime environment and a OpenGL widget, but also a large set of widgets to draw UI elements with.